# How much does a 'good planet' cost?

Tags: planets, economy, terraforming

If you had the technology, how much would an economically feasible, biosphere grade, sustainable habitat, environmentally acumen planet 'cost'?

Doing a project comparison, these options are used to narrow the technology and maintenance to only two outcomes:

1) The Genesis Device-
http://m.startrek.com/database_article/project-genesis

2) Project Prometheus-
http://www.weylandindustries.com/investor

There are other projects being considered, but these two appear to be most popular. Topics such as overall cost, return on investment, long term maintenance are optional. The original question of "how much would a good planet cost" has already been answered by the forum. Thanks.

Comment: Created from scratch, or found in fair/good condition and sold?  Craigslist or open market?  What currency?

Comment: One would need a lot of guesses to answer that.

Comment: The terraforming tag seems to imply that the planet was not pre-made. Is that the case? Was the entire planet constructed by beings, or did it form naturally?

Comment: Promising question, but needs a fair bit of fleshing out. "The technology"? What technology? Godlike tech? 2 cents. Alien series? Trillions of dollars.

Comment: http://www.weylandindustries.com/terraforming

Answer (score 4):

## It Depends

How big is this planet? What is the composition of the planet?

What about the availability of other planets of similar quality?

I'm going to assume earth-like planet, both of composition, mass, etc.

Vsauce did an [entertaining video](http://youtu.be/nt6ab7BTlgE) on this. They reference an individual who says the earth (at current market value) is about 15.6 sextillion dollars ($ 15,809,800,000,000,000,000,000)! You will need to master the equation from Greg Laughlin (found [on his blog](http://oklo.org/2009/03/12/too-cheap-to-meter/)) to determine the value of the planet in question. Greg Laughlin is an astronomer, among other things, with a PhD in Astronomy and Astrophysics.

However, supply and demand are fickle things, and if you only had 1 not earth planet to colonize, your cost for that planet would rocket up to unimaginable sums of money. (As if 15.6 sextillion wasn't unimaginable enough!) If you had a supply of 'good planets' so much that every one could have their own, then they're almost worthless, perhaps as expensive as a home.

Given our experiences with habitable planets, which is to say that they exist, there appears to be [8 confirmed ones](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2015-003). There are a [lot of exoplanets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discoveries_of_exoplanets), though, so it seems that habitable planets are rare. Supply/Demand would place them closer to the "cannot be purchased" values than "worth nothing" values.

Comment: For the informal record, I find this question and answer interesting, but small-minded. I, personally, find the worth of a habitable planet invaluable, of incalculable worth, as it can be an ever-lasting and ever-new human experience, on which I cannot place a value.

Comment: Well, the question asked about the cost, not the value. If you are starving, a piece of bread will be invaluable to you (value=unimaginably high), even if someone gives it to you for free (cost=zero).